# LCD clears itself when potentiometer contrast is too low

Tags: arduino, lcd, display

I'm making a project that requires an LCD, and the project was working fine on my breadboard for testing.

I moved it to my final product, but now my LCD stops displaying text after a few minutes, or when the potentiometer value is too low.

One thing that really gets my attention is that if the potentiometer is fully high, the LCD doesn't clear by itself. When I lower it, it happens again. I have a refresh rate in this project as well for about every 250 milliseconds. Here is the code for my project along with its schematic.

Schematic:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you have the pot connected incorrectly, so it shorts out the supply voltage.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany what could it possible short to?

Comment: If you swap wiper and end of the element, it will present a direct short across the power when turned to one end. This can happen when footprint pin numbers don't match the schematic symbol.

Comment: I made sure the footprint is right, and it is as far as I know. I've also been thinking that it might be a short between pins 3 and 4. This is because the lcd works for the first few seconds, but stops a while afterwards. Even if I don't touch the potentiometer.

Comment: Yes, that's another possibility.

Comment: And also if there is a short, shouldn't that just turn the lcd off in general?

Comment: maybe  you swapped 3 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the potentiometer was cheap. I got a new one and it works as good as new.